# resetting/clearing the previous (user input) contents of a div on submit

Tags: javascript

(I've been asked to only use Javascript. I know I could use jQuery or something else to do this.)

So, I have a text field for inputting things and a submit button that prints them inside a div. I'd like only one submitted thing to be visible in the div at a time (currently, previously submitted things also show up).

I figured I'm supposed to use `document.getElementById("leftblock").reset();` to do this, but I can't get it to work. Either I'm not supposed to use it or I can't figure the right spot to place it. Any ideas on how to get this to work?

A (simplified) version of my current code:

JS:

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
  if ( -- no need to include this -- ) {
    document.getElementById("leftblock").innerHTML = "asdfghjkl"
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="myText" value="">
```

```
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="myButton">Submit</button>
```

```
  <div class="mydiv">
    <p id="leftblock"></p>
  </div>
```

Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: `reset()` works for forms and form elements, not divs

Comment: Use ``document.getElementById("leftblock").innerText = '';``  to cleare the data for any div, span, p tags etc.

Comment: innerText is safer that innerHTML as per @NotABot example code.

Comment: Thank you so much, that works! :) I tried document.getElementById("leftblock").innerHTML = ''; before but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite the `<p>` with the current textfield value:

```
<input type="text" id="myText" value="">
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="myButton">Submit</button>
<div class="mydiv">
  <p id="leftblock"></p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
  document.getElementById("leftblock").innerText = x;
}
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/jmo9t8d2/2/